# Which database EAN sandbox uses in testing environment?

Tags: web, sandbox

I want to ask that, when we use EAN (Expedia Affiliated Network) Sandbox for testing environment, which Database is used by Sandbox?

I mean is it Localhost database or there is some mirror database of Live Server Database hosted by EAN that serves the requests of Sandbox?

Or if it is like we can use any of these two databases (Considering that there exists Mirror Database) as per configuration given to sandbox, then how to do that configuration? I know that there is CID to be given as 55505 for testing environment, but I am not sure about databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Expedia Affiliate Network (EAN)](http://devhub.ean.com/V3sandbox/index.asp) sandbox uses production data. The sandbox's usage of CID 55505 and an apiKey that is setup in a limited fashion is what is meant by testing environment. Also, the webpage is designed to be educational rather then something you would use to sell hotels.